# store contents in an array then print them all at once

Tags: c, raspberry-pi

I have a circuit where a pulse is generated every 8 clock cycles, and at those pulses I want to dump and print all the contents of my array.

I have GPIO pins that read the value in it, and I am storing it into an Array.

The only thing I know of to print the contents of an array is through a for loop, but I find that it slows my pulse program too much

I would like to know is there a way to store the entire content of an Array then simply print all of its content at once in just a single pulse of a clock.... so something like store everything in something and once the 8th clock cycle comes print all of it then repeat.

Comment: Can you provide some code?

Comment: People sometimes like to give the idea that "loops are slow", but that's wrong. It's not the loop that's slow, it's the fact that you're doing a lot of work, assisted by a loop. It's not clear at all, missing more information, but it seems to me like that's the case for you. If you're printing every element in an array, you're going to use a loop. It *sounds* (though this is just me guessing from the little in the question) like the issue is that it's just plain slow to print a lot of values.

Comment: You cannot print "_at once_" at all. Every output channel needs time, and commonly this is by far longer than the overhead of the loop you use. So yes, we need more details, and optimally a [mre] with an explanation _why_ it does not fulfill your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You can print all elements like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
int arr[5],i;

printf("Enter the five integer value: ");

for(i = 0 ; i < 5; i++) {
    scanf("%d",&arr[i]);
    }
    
printf("Elements of array is: \n");
for(i = 0 ; i < 5; i++) {
    printf("%d\t",arr[i]);
    }
return 0;
```

}